# How can I choose the node version when using .nvm to install

Tags: javascript, npm, nvm

In the terminal, using nvm, I would like to run `npm install <something>` and have npm install the package in the node version that I'm currently using.  Currently, no matter what version I have set using nvm, by default, nvm is installing all packages in node version 9.4.0.

I have ran the command `nvm use v10.15.3` which switches me to that current version.  When I run a command `npm install -g ionic@latest` (or any global command) it always installs it in the version 9.4.0 directory.

My output after running the command...

```
.../.nvm/versions/node/v9.4.0/bin/ionic -> .../.nvm/versions/node/v9.4.0/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic
```

This happens even though I'm currently on 10.15.3 (I would expect to install in the directory `v10.15.3` and not `v9.4.0`

I'm using `nvm version 0.34.0`.

bash_profile

```
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"

source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

Comment: one thing that I tried which works is if I go directly to the directory `.../.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/` and run `npm install ionic@latest`, this will install properly, but I can't imagine this is what everyone else is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the global version of node installed.

```
nvm install node --reinstall-packages-from=node
```

is useful for moving your tools to the new Node.js version.

See usage: https://github.com/creationix/nvm#usage

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a path issue, can you add your bashrc, npmrc or profile to the question?

Comment: I'm quite sure this a path issue now, I tried it on my machine and the behavior you want is the default one.

Comment: your bash_profile is ok, try inspecting your npmrc/bashrc

Comment: also, the answer your marked as a solution is just reinstalling the node modules from your previous node installation in the new one, which is quite useful but doesn't fix the problem, you'll have to issue that command every time you install a new package

Comment: That's correct, the marked answer solves my problem for now, but doesn't fix the problem overall.  I checked my ".nvm/.npmrc" file and all thats there is "package-lock=false"., my bash_rc has '[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion'.  Looks like at some point I screwed up my .nvm settings  
"